# Highcharts highstock drag with ipad touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I'm working on a highcharts (highstock) implementation where I don't want to show the navigator or scrollbar at the bottom, so on the desktop you'd just use your mouse to click and drag in the chart to navigate along the series.

Does anybody know what the best way to do a similar action on the ipad would be?  At the moment the ipad just picks up the touch on the chart and displays the tooltip with the crosshair.

Any help would be great, thanks.

http://jsbin.com/irixeh/10/edit

Comment: This feature is planned for Highcharts 3.0, see roadmap: http://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap